# how to get all attributes of a person in dpbedia, not just specific attributes queried

Tags: sparql, wikipedia, dbpedia

I know you can get a list of all of the attributes and a list of all people via the simple query:

```
select distinct ?property where {
         ?instance a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person> . 
         ?instance ?property ?obj . }
```

but how do I get all information of a person available without having to enter in each of those quantities? Select * doesn't extract all variables as it would in SQL.

```
SELECT * WHERE
{ ?p a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person> .
?p <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/knownFor> ?knownFor . }
LIMIT 10
```

This only gives me the person and the knownfor attribute. I thought select * gives all quantities? In any case, I want not just the person or their knownfor attribute, but all values possible for each person.

Comment: Do you want to get all the attributes and values for an specific person?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Though I just want the values with each column being an attribute.

Comment: I think it's not possible having attributes as columns, because the response of a sparql query is a mapping having varibles as columns and the different possible values for that variables as rows

Comment: @conca Not only that, but since RDF isn't a database, there's no fixed set of properties that a person can have, so there's no real limit on how many "columns" there would be in the results.

Comment: As an aside: `SELECT *` _does_ return all variables. But "all variables" means "all variables declared in the query", not "all possible attributes/values in the data".

Comment: OK thanks. Where can I get a list of all the attributes which I can query? I found the /ontology list but for say, programming languages, it doesn't match the data which is able to be queried? e.g. "appearedin" as per the infobox.

Comment: @Griff the ontology is that list. But an ontology is not a database schema: the instance data is not _required_ to follow it. Some properties may be missing for some instances, and indeed properties not mentioned in the ontology may be used as well. An ontology is a vocabulary _description_, not a structure _prescription_.

Comment: @JeenBroekstra ahh ok. still learning. so if I wanted a instance of an ontology say "programming languages", how would I find what term to use ?XXX to search over if the property does not appear in the ontology?

Comment: @Griff there are some properties which almost always are present. `rdfs:label` defines a human-readable label, and (in DBPedia certainly) is present for almost all topics. So if you have the string "Programming Languages" and want to find the corresponding DBPedia topic, querying the values of `rdfs:label` properties is a good way to do it. See some of the related questions on DBPedia and SPARQL, you'll find examples of this there.

Answer (score 6):

You cant't get the attributes as columns, but still it's possible to get al properties/values as rows.

This query gets all properties for all the resources of type Person:

```
SELECT ?person ?prop ?value WHERE 
{
    ?person a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person> .
    ?person ?prop ?value .
    FILTER ( langMatches(lang(?value), "en") )   
}
LIMIT 100
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: That gives me no results sorry. It is the language filter part which is wrong I think.

Comment: Indeed, it should be `lang(?value)`. Or perhaps even better, use `langMatches(str(?value), "en")`. Or leave out the filter altogether if you really want _all_ data about a person...

Comment: I change `langMatches(str(?value), "en")` for `langMatches(lang(?value), "en")`. Now the query is working.

Answer (score 4):

@conca already gave you a simple SELECT query that returns the data you want.

As an alternative, you could look at a CONSTRUCT or DESCRIBE query, the result of which will not be a table-like structure, but an actual RDF graph. For broad "tell me everything you know about a particular topic"-type queries, these are often easier to work with:

```
CONSTRUCT 
WHERE { ?person a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person> ; 
                ?prop ?value . 
} 
LIMIT 100
```

or

```
DESCRIBE 
WHERE { ?person a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person> } 
LIMIT 100
```